# Problem launching Magento 2 wizard on my MAC

Tags: magento2.2, setup, php-7.2

I have a problem starting the installation process on my mac. Can't launch the set up wizard. These are  the changes I made to my **php.ini** file `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/conf/php.ini:`

```
max_execution_time = 18000
max_input_time = 16000
memory_limit = 1024M
```

I restarted **MAMP** multiple times still nothing appear on the browser.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see from your php.ini path you are using **PHP 7.2**. Magento 2.2 is currently not compatible with PHP 7.2 (this is on the list for Magento 2.3). So please try again with **PHP 7.1**.